# Firebase @google-cloud/firestore package Typescript error Duplicate identifier 'DocumentData'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase cloud functions using Typescript and every thing works fine. At my code i make one of variables of type `DocumentReference` and `GeoPoint` that's make vs code to import it

`import { GeoPoint, DocumentReference } from '@google-cloud/firestore'`

```
function offsetSlightly(location:GeoPoint) {
     //some code here
  return new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)
}
```

So i need to add that node module i added using command

`npm install @google-cloud/firestore`

And every thing looks fine when i try to deploy i get a lot of Duplicate identifier eg DocumentData, UpdateData, GeoPoint ..etc

Error:

```
node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:28:15 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'DocumentData'.


28   export type DocumentData = {[field: string]: any};
```

That's my package.json 
{

```
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.14.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.4",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.4",
    "twilio": "^3.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I don't know the problem but i think it's some conflict in packages.I'm android developer have a little experience in Node. Any help?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the minimal code that reproduces the problem, along with the exact error messages that it generates.  Without code, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I put the code is needed it's package conflict i think. I have a variable location:GeoPoint and to get GeoPoint i need to add google cloud package that what case the problem @DougStevenson

Comment: You put an import statement, but you're missing the code where those imported types are actually used.

Comment: OK i added one function @DougStevenson

Comment: Add the exact error messages also, please.  Really, what we need is a full example that reproduces the error.

Comment: I added it. Part of it the rest is the same but with different data types @DougStevenson

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of importing the classes from the standalone Firestore SDK just create type aliases on Firebase Admin SDK's Firestore:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

type GeoPoint = admin.firestore.GeoPoint
type DocumentReference = admin.firestore.DocumentReference
```

Comment: This is not the best solution. As the other answer correctly stated, you can use firestore directly from the admin module, and you should do so to avoid this error.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong imports.

In cloud functions you can use admin SDK to get data from Firestore.

Here is an example of adding a GeoPoint in a collection
admin.firestore().collection('mycollection').add({ location:new admin.firestore.GeoPoint(1.0, 1.0) });

And this is the import statement

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

For more info - https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: You are right here. but i just need @google-cloud/firestore to get the data types why that case a problem?

Comment: Well technically that shouldn't be a problem but, using admin SDK is more easier
Well you can refer to this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore

You have to initialise the SDK with your project

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't the reason. But ensure that you are using latest node and npm version. And also in docs it mentions to save as Dev dependency --save flag. I don't think it would have caused the problem but you could give it a try

Comment: It doesn't work i will use new admin.firestore.GeoPoint for now until i figure this out. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem. I will also look for solution and get back once I find it

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. A separate node_modules got created within "functions/node-modules/firebase-admin". I deleted it manually and got it resolved. 
I hope this might be one of the solutions.