# Error: TS6200 with Firestore dependancies - unable to compile angular project after running updates

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to run my code locally with `ng serve` and I am getting the following error and I can't seem to resolve it. Looking for help:

```
Error: node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1 - error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: DocumentData, UpdateData, Firestore, GeoPoint, Transaction, WriteBatch, SetOptions, WriteResult, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, QueryDocumentSnapshot, OrderByDirection, WhereFilterOp, Query, QuerySnapshot, DocumentChangeType, CollectionReference, FieldValue, FieldPath, Timestamp, v1beta1, v1, OK, CANCELLED, UNKNOWN, INVALID_ARGUMENT, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, NOT_FOUND, ALREADY_EXISTS, PERMISSION_DENIED, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, FAILED_PRECONDITION, ABORTED, OUT_OF_RANGE, UNIMPLEMENTED, INTERNAL, UNAVAILABLE, DATA_LOSS, UNAUTHENTICATED, FirebaseFirestore
```

It then continues giving locations for where the errors are occurring:

```
23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
   ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:23:1
    23 declare namespace FirebaseFirestore {
       ~~~~~~~
    Conflicts are in this file.


Error: functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:155:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'string'.

155     [key: string]: any; // Accept other properties, such as GRPC settings.
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:302:5 - error TS2374: Duplicate index signature for type 'string'.

302     [key: string]: any; // Accept other properties, such as GRPC settings.
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:385:55 - error TS2314: Generic type 'UpdateData' requires 1 type argument(s).

385     update(documentRef: DocumentReference<any>, data: UpdateData,
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:473:55 - error TS2314: Generic type 'UpdateData' requires 1 type argument(s).

473     update(documentRef: DocumentReference<any>, data: UpdateData,
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~


Error: functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/types/firestore.d.ts:669:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'UpdateData' requires 1 type argument(s).

669     update(data: UpdateData, precondition?: Precondition): Promise<WriteResult>;
```

I am running the following versions on my system:

Node: 14.18.0

npm: 8.19.0

firebase: 11.15.0

angularCLI: 14.2.7

Angular: 14.2.8

typescript: 4.8.4

I have tried deleting my `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder, and reinstall with `npm`, but this is still not fixing the issue. Any help would be appreciated so I can get back to deploying locally on my computer. Thanks!

Comment: can you try the workaround  mentioned in this github [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/734#issuecomment-627742859)

Comment: For a temporary fix on my computer, this seems to work. Thank you for the thread and the suggestion. It is compiling now, but still would like to find a solution so this line of code is unnecessary.

Comment: Ethan, did you ever find a better fix than skip lib check?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround adding `skipLibCheck` in tsconfig to true allows you to continue deploying

Check  if a separate node_modules directory and any lock files got created you should delete those and reinstall the dependencies.

As mentioned in this [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/734#issuecomment-566816779) you can also check if two version of Firestore were included via NPM's dependency resolution

Also check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57522485/18265638) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63602466/deploy-error-cloud-functions-firebase-deploy)

If the issue still persists I suggest to raise your issue in [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues).